# VSTS Condition for a RElease pipeline task

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops

I have a Release pipeline where I would like to execute a cleanup task in case of a failure of any of the previous tasks or if the pipeline was cancelled.

I am using the Classic editor and not pipeline as a code. My default options do not satisfy my requirement.

I would like to execute the task to something like this " Execute this task if the Pipeline fails or is Cancelled".

**Is there anyway I can do this in a release pipeline ?**

I know it can probably be done in a Build pipeline where there could be Build pipeline variables for this scenario. But not sure how I can do it in a Release pipeline

Comment: I found a way to do it or(failed(),canceled()) in the condition did the trick

Comment: Hi friend, it occurs that you've found the solution yourself, you can [add it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As **Sid** comments, you can use `or(failed(),canceled())` in task condition to run one task when any previous task faled or deployment canceled.

But note, if you cancel the release at the very start (create release, cancel it), the task won't run.